# move_uploaded_file falhando

Tags: php, servidor

Olá, pessoal, tudo bem? Eu estou com um problema para salvar imagens dentro do servidor. Esse código eu encontrei na internet, mas não funciona. Me retorna alguns erros. Podem me ajudar?

Este é o código:

```
if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'lutadorUm' ][ 'name' ] ) && $_FILES[ 'lutadorUm' ][ 'error' ] == 0 ) {
    echo 'Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'lutadorUm' ][ 'name' ] . '</strong><br />';
    echo 'Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong > ' . $_FILES[ 'lutadorUm' ][ 'type' ] . ' </strong ><br />';
    echo 'Temporáriamente foi salvo em: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'lutadorUm' ][ 'tmp_name' ] . '</strong><br />';
    echo 'Seu tamanho é: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'lutadorUm' ][ 'size' ] . '</strong> Bytes<br /><br />';

    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES[ 'lutadorUm' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
    $nome = $_FILES[ 'lutadorUm' ][ 'name' ];

    $extensao = pathinfo ( $nome, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

    $extensao = strtolower ( $extensao );

    if ( strstr ( '.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao ) ) {

        $novoNome = uniqid ( time () ) . ".".$extensao;

        $destino = 'imagens/' . $novoNome;

        if (move_uploaded_file ( $arquivo_tmp, $destino ) ) {
            echo 'Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>' . $destino . '</strong><br />';
            echo ' < img src = "' . $destino . '" />';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Erro ao salvar o arquivo. Aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita.<br />';
            echo $destino;
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Você poderá enviar apenas arquivos "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png"<br />';
        echo $destino;
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!';
}
```

Este são os erros:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(imagens/149149930358e679279a144.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\back_classes\envioUfc.php on line 34
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\php6E3B.tmp' to 'imagens/149149930358e679279a144.jpg' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\back_classes\envioUfc.php on line 34

Obs: Eu tenho a pasta dentro da pasta do projeto. E mesmo quando apontei diretamente para o servidor, não funcionou. Por exemplo: "localhost/back/imagens/".

Comment: Como assim? "C://users/usuario/back/imagens", é isso?

Comment: Obrigado! Era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O caminho do teu .php não deve estar relativo a pasta imagens, só vendo a estrutura de pastas do projeto especifico para ter certeza, pelo caminho `back_classes\envioUfc.php` creio que a pasta `imagens` esteja fora de de `back_classes` então deve usar assim:

```
$destino = '../imagens/' . $novoNome;
```

Se não funcionar é porque o caminho esta errado, para ajustar também pode tentar o caminho absoluto (supondo que a pas imagens esteja dentro de htdocs):

```
 $destino = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/imagens/' . $novoNome;
```

Se estiver dentro de `back_classes` e a falha ocorre é porque você esta incluindo o `envioUfc.php` em outro ficheiro `.php` (com include ou require) que esteja em um nivel diferente, então pode experimentar isto:

```
 $destino = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/back_classes/imagens/' . $novoNome;
```

Quando for enviar a um servidor de produção terá que ajustar este caminho absoluto.

Um exemplo para facilitar e evitar manutenção ou ajustes seria criar um arquivo global que deve ser incluido em todos arquivos com `require_once`, neste arquivo global.php deve conter isto:

```
<?php
//Define a constante
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

E nos arquivos como `index.php` e outros adicione isto acima de tudo:

```
<?php
require_once 'global.php';
```

Se estiver em uma pasta diferente da pasta aonde esta o index.php, use assim:

```
<?php
require_once '../global.php';
```

E o $destino deve ficar assim:

```
$destino = ROOT_PATH . 'imagens/' . $novoNome;
```

Comment: Okay, vou fazer isso, obrigado!!

Comment: Desculpa, mas aparentemente ele não ta salvando no servidor. No localhost eu encontro o arquivo dentro da pasta imagens, mas no servidor ela não ta lá. Eu falei que funcionou, porque eu vi que tinha salvo o link no banco

Comment: Okay, mas eu usei o global.php como você sugeriu.

Comment: Ocorre o mesmo erro

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56679/discussion-between-krint-and-guilherme-nascimento).