# Como importar o conteúdo FPDF para Zend2?

Tags: zend-framework-2, fpdf

Estou criando uma página de orçamento com o Zend 2, para imprimir com o FPDF.

O problema é que não sei fazer a importação.

**O erro é esse:**

Warning: require(/php/sistema_real/public/aditivos/fpdf/fpdf.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\sistema_real\application\views\scripts\orcamento\imprimir.phtml on line 4

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/php/sistema_real/public/aditivos/fpdf/fpdf.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\php\sistema_real\application/../library;C:\xampp\htdocs\php\sistema_real\library;.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\sistema_real\application\views\scripts\orcamento\imprimir.phtml on line 4

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O trecho do código que faz o require:**

```
<?php

$end = $this->baseUrl('aditivos/fpdf/');
require($end.'fpdf.php');
```

**Aqui o trecho do Controller:**

```
public function imprimirAction()
  {
  $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

  }
```

Comment: `No such file or directory` ~ *"não existe arquivo ou pasta"*, resumindo o arquivo fpdf.php não existe na pasta, ou a pasta fpdf não esta dentro da pasta aditivos, também é possivel que a pasta aditivos esteja com alguma letra faltando ou a mais.

Comment: Mas o endereço tá certinho... o documento tá lá:

C:\xampp\htdocs\php\sistema_real\public\aditivos\fpdf

Comment: e o fpdf.php esta lá?

Comment: Sim sim, já conferi várias vezes hehe

Comment: <?php

$end = $this->baseUrl('aditivos/fpdf/');
require($end.'fpdf.php');

Comment: É pra editar a pergunta -.- ... Coloca o código relevante, eu não sei p que é este `baseUrl` amigo. Até aonde sei isto não é nativo do PHP, estou aguardando.

Comment: Sim, esse baseUrl é do Zendframework 2

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, eu não sabia do `APPLICATION_PATH`, veja se assim fica mais fácil.

Comment: Thank you very much Guilherme! Tá funcionando aqui com a solução de antes da edição, já já vou testar as outras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solução com próprio Zend

Após a edição notei que estava carregando o fpdf pelo Zend mesmo então pode usar assim:

```
<?php
require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/aditivos/fpdf/fpdf.php';
```

Se falha faça assim:

```
<?php
require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/public/aditivos/fpdf/fpdf.php';
```

> Mas realmente eu não acho uma boa ideia deixar as libs e coisas assim dentro da `public`

---

### Solução rápida (antes de editar a pergunta):

O teu require deve estar assim:

```
require '/php/sistema_real/public/aditivos/fpdf/fpdf.php';
```

O que faz ele procurar isto: `c:/php/sistema_real/public/aditivos/fpdf/fpdf.php` e não isto: `c:/xampp/htdocs/php/sistema_real/public/aditivos/fpdf/fpdf.php`, pois a base do PHP por padrão não se baseia no Apache e sim no próprio sistema, no entanto é possível configurar o php.ini para isto, mas é algo que não acho necessário.

Basta fazer o ajuste para algo como:

```
require 'c:/xampp/htdocs/php/sistema_real/public/aditivos/fpdf/fpdf.php';
```

Ou então criar um arquivo global.php como expliquei em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195566/3635

Também pode se pensar no uso do spl e namespaces para basear o teu carregamento por isto (ou por composer):

- [O que é spl_autoloader_register em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88039/3635)
- [PSR-4 em um projeto MVC ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80060/3635)
- [Quais são as diferenças entre __autoload e spl_autoload_register?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75105/3635)
- [O que significa PSR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32295/3635)
- [Classe autoload PSR4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91512/3635)